# Submit PHP - why isn't that working?

Tags: php, forms, button, post, submit

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))  {
   // I want to get here after pressing the Sign in button
}

if(!user::isLogged()){
echo '
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
          <form method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input name="login" type="text" placeholder="Login" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
          </form>
          </form>
';
}
?>
```

Why isn't the submit button working?

How should I fix it? I've been new in website's programming, I've got no idea what's wrong here.

Comment: Why do you have two form elements nested?

Comment: We have no idea what "doesn't work" mean. Doesn't it have a job? Doesn't it want a job? Does it want to apply for a job?

Comment: Nested `form` elements is invalid HTML.  Fix your markup before trying to debug errors.

Comment: it just doesn't do anything after pressing the submit button.
should i just do something like this?

Comment: <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="POST">

Comment: Yes, both class and method should be inside one form tag. You might also want to add the action="somewhere" there. Just a suggestion, I feel very uncomfortable with writing html code inside php echo ' your html code'. I would instead do: if(!user::isLogged()) { include('form.php'); } //where form.php simply contains the same html code for form. You could also try making a separate login page and if a user is not logged in, redirect them to the login page.

Comment: Anyway, I just found out that even if I don't press the sign in button - the action is being done. I've added "echo" into that if(isset) and it was done even though I haven't pressed that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Captain Red. I'm gonna use this. This website looks like this, though: http://prntscr.com/9j526d

Comment: Well in that case, I see that you have the login form in the header section so redirect would not be option for you here. However, you could write the form part in a separate page and include it there if the user is not logged in.

Comment: This way I'm gonna need to add 2 files, user_notlogged.php as well as user_logged.php, if i understood right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!user::isLogged()){
echo '
          <form method="POST" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input name="login" type="text" placeholder="Login" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
          </form>
';
}
?>
```

Your 'form' was declared into another one and without 'method'. That was the mistake.

Comment: Thank you!
Could you take a look, if that's gonna work well?http://pastebin.com/gnAGzhGV (ignore the wrong variables' names in some places)

Comment: Yes, I think, it will work. Preventing injections is a good practice!